# IOptions not working with TinyIOC/NancyFX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nancy, tinyioc

I'm trying to implement the Options Pattern (as recommended [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects)) on a project with `NancyFX`/`TinyIOC` but it's not working.

I'm registering the Options on the `Startup.cs.ConfigureServices` method but when I try to inject the settings on my class `TinyIoc` throws:

> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: AppSettings.

I think this is because the Options Pattern uses `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` but `Nancy` uses `TinyIoc` as default so `TinyIoc` tries to resolve `IOptions<AppSettings>` and fails.

Is there a way to use `IOptions<>` with `TinyIoc`?

Here's my code:

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

### MyService.cs

```
public SearchService(IOptions<AppSettings> config)
{
}
```

Error:

> Application startup exception: 
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Something went wrong when trying to satisfy one of the dependencies
>   during composition, make sure that you've registered all new
>   dependencies in the container and inspect the innerexception for more
>   details.
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to
>   resolve type: Nancy.NancyEngine
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.Routing.DefaultRequestDispatcher
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.Routing.RouteCache
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   MyProject.MyService
>
> Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException:
>   Unable to resolve type:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.IOptions`1[[MyProject.AppSettings,
>   MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Some extra info:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Nancy": "1.4.3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

DNX runtime version:

```
1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found the answer. I had to create a custom bootstrap and register the resolved dependency on TinyIoc:

Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy(new NancyOptions
        {
            Bootstrapper = new CustomBootstrapper(app)
        }));
    }
```

CustomBootstrapper.cs:

```
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register<IOptions<AppSettings>>(_app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>());
    }
```

Comment: What is _app within CustomBootstrapper?

Comment: `app` should be a `IApplicationBuilder`. However, you can request an instance of `IServiceProvider` in constructor and use `_serviceProvider.GetService` instead.